# What is the meaning of this?

Tags: translation

I was on the internet, and I found this slogan 我待国足如初恋.  Does this mean "I treat national soccer like first love?"

Answer (score 4):

It's the second half of internet phrase “XX虐我千百遍，我待XX如初恋” (XX has hurt me a thousand times, but I still regard it as my first love.)

In the case of 国足, it's a way to show the unconditional support for the national soccer league.

Comment: Thanks for providing a source for this. I didn't realize there is this first half. I was a bit puzzled by the sentiment of "treating a soccer team like your first love" and thought it might be some kind of silly hyperbole. Now it all makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Without too much context, it is probably "I treat the national soccer team like my first love." As many have expressed in the forum, the more context you can provide, the better a translator can do. But I think you've got the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

it means we love our soccer team , look forward to the team can win in the next game just like we met the team for the first time with enthusiasm ,although it always lost games and breaks our heart.